# JS scroll till element is in the middle of viewport

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, css-tables, scrollto

I have a table with a lot of items in it. To see the items, I have to scroll from left to right. Now I want to scroll a specific item. But I want that the item is shown in the middle of the visible part of the table.

I tried to get the left side of the item and the half of the width to get the middle and to scroll to that point. But that didn't work out. So I tried to add the half of the width of the table. That also didn't work. The funny thing is that if I change the width of the site it scrolls to a different position of the visible part.

I created a short and nice example of my problem:

```js
var dummy = $(".dummy").clone();
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
 var item = dummy.clone();
 if (i == 123)
  item.addClass("scrollTo");

 $("tr").append(item);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 var scrollToElement = $(".scrollTo");
 var scrollToElementFullWidthTillMiddle = scrollToElement.offset().left + (scrollToElement.width() / 2);
 var scrollTo = scrollToElementFullWidthTillMiddle + ($(".wrapper").width() / 2);

 $(".wrapper")[0].scrollLeft = scrollTo;
});
```

```css
body{
 width: 800px;
}

.wrapper{
 overflow-x: auto;
 width: calc(100% - 180px);
 margin-left: 180px;
}

table{
 table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

td:nth-child(2n){
 background: gray;
}

td div{
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
}

.scrollTo{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td class="dummy"><div></div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any easy way to scroll a few pixels? Because I have that theory that it's not using pixels for scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using pixels for scrolling, but the offset position is not equal to the scrolling position.
To test it you can output the value of `$(".wrapper td").first().offset().left` and `$(".wrapper")[0].scrollLeft` (before updating it) in the console.

So this is how I could solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scrollToElement = $(".scrollTo");
    var scrollToElementFullWidthTillMiddle = scrollToElement.offset().left + (scrollToElement.outerWidth() / 2);
    var scrollTo = scrollToElementFullWidthTillMiddle - $(".wrapper td").first().offset().left - ($(".wrapper").outerWidth()/2);

    $(".wrapper")[0].scrollLeft = scrollTo;
});
```